# What does enter key mean in linux terminal?

Tags: c, linux, terminal

I've got a very simple C function below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        putchar(c);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I use gcc on my linux os terminal to test it.
The result is:

```
d
d
e
e
f
f
5
5
56
56
```

I just want to know: 

1. Why every time I press my Enter Key, the terminal repeats the character I just typed?

2. Why I put two characters (56), and that works too, how does that work?

3. Why only the Enter Key makes the terminal repeat, not other keys? 

4. What does pressing Enter Key mean in a linux terminal or for a C program like this?

Comment: the code is echoing everything you type? what is confusing about that?

Comment: your app just copies the input. Some of the questions about repetition are just plain weird.

Comment: @ChrisTurner It's just why the Enter Key does the job, why not other keys.

Comment: buffering......

Comment: Actually it's a bit more involved than that, stdin is line-buffered which is why 56 is echoed all at once and not first the 5 then the 6.

Comment: Please note that [`getchar`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) returns an `int`. This is actually important in the comparison to `EOF`. Your "character" variable `c` should also be an `int`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yeah, you are right. I got this code from the C programming language and int is used. I will correct it.

Comment: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/117985-cinget-without-having-to-pressing-enter/

Comment: The tty is in canonical mode, and is simply buffering data until you hit return.  When you hit return, it sends everything in its buffer to your program.  If you put the tty in raw mode, it will send data more frequently.

Comment: http://osr600doc.sco.com/en/SDK_sysprog/_TTY_in_Raw_Mode.html

Comment: In addition to your TTY being in canonical mode, your standard input stream is most likely in line-buffered mode, as that is the default in POSIX when the standard input comes from a TTY. See the description of the `setbuf` and/or `setvbuf` functions to change that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Terminal input is managed through a kernel specific object known as "tty". This tty buffers what you input before (by default) delivering data to your process. This is very useful because it lets you (as a user) correct your command line before sending it to processes. Tty buffering is usually in line-mode, meaning that input data is delivered either if buffer is full or a newline is inputed.

So when you type a single char, that char is not available to your process, it is inside the tty buffer. Then you type a new line and both are available to your process which is then able to read the first one, pushes it to the output then reads the newline and also pushes it to the output.

Tty's behaviour can be changed, see command `stty` for example. I encourage you to read about "POSIX terminals".

Comment: "_either if buffer is full_" - How much characters/bytes would that be? Is its size implementation-dependant? What is its typical size?

Comment: @CoolGuy can't remember but some hundreds at least.

Answer (score 3):

> Why every time I press my Enter Key, the terminal repeats the character I just typed?

By default the terminal handler echos everything you type back to you. Your program is also echoing everything you type back to you. You can change this behaviour from the command line with [stty](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stty), although, to be honest, you might find it confusing. There's also a [POSIX C API](https://linux.die.net/man/3/termios) to do the same which might be more useful.

> Why I put two characters (56), and that works too, how does that work?

Every character you type gets sent to the program. Your program reads them all one at a time.

> Why only the Enter Key makes the terminal repeat, not other keys?

The normal mode of the terminal program is to buffer characters until a newline is received and then to send them all at once. Your program actually spends most of its time sleeping in `getchar()` waiting for characters, then when you press new line, a flurry of activity happens while it processes each of the characters one at a time.